# next js 13 keeps refreshing the page on router push

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I'm buildng a search app with NextJs 13 and the issue that i have is that it refresh the page every time when i click search button and that's only happening when i push it on vercel. When I run it locally both with "npm run build and npm start dev" everything works normally, the page is not refreshing. I tried with "shallow true" but i get still the same behavior. I also tried with e.prevertDefault. When the page refresh i loose input state and I get no results found every time. I'm using SWR hook for fetching data. I'm not using form for this.
Here is my code:

## Result Page

```
const {
  data: cases,
  error,
  isLoading,
} = useSWR(
startFetch
  ? `https://<url>/search/${isSearchQueryParams}`
  : null,
 fetcher,
 {
  keepPreviousData: true,
 }
);
```

## Hero Component / Index Page

```
<div onClick={handleClick}>
   <ButtonBlueWhite height={47} width={200} title={"Search"} />
</div>

 const handleClick = () => {
  setStartFetch(true);
  router.push("/results");
};
```

Answer (score -1):

The method to achieve shallow routing without a page refresh when using the Next 13 App Directory is `router.replace()`.

[Next13 Docs - useRouter API Reference](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#userouter)

Updated `handleClick` function:

```js
const handleClick = () => {
  setStartFetch(true);
  router.replace("/results");
};
```

Comment: The difference between push and replace is history. It has nothing to do with making a shallow routing change. The way to achieve shallow routing is to add a `layout.tsx`